What are the safe assumptions I can make when installing a wall oven without model/serial?
I'm building a basement ADU and a net new kitchen. I was a gently used Meile oven and want to wire this into my new basement subpanel. Most of the sticker was removed so I can't find the model/serial.
My panel:

150a sub panel
Serviced by a 125a breaker on single phase 120v 200a main panel

Appliance:

Brand: Meile
Width: 30"
4-wire (green, white, black, and red)
Single heating element
Convection fan
Remaining sticker says "208/12—"




Based on appearances, I found a potential match here: https://fortmyers.craigslist.org/lee/ppd/d/bonita-springs-miele-30-masterchef/7764812006.html This listing shows a sticker similar to mine where I conclude that my sticker should read "208/120v". Likely "60HZ" and "3200W" as well. Is this a safe assumption?


Does the slash simply mean that the appliance and specifically the heating element will work with 120v (effectively 240v with a 4-wire connection) or 208v?
My plan is to run 10-3 wire to a 30 amp double pole breaker. If it's 3200W then divide that by 120v and get 26.66 amps.
Anyone see any issues with that plan? Thanks so much for your time!

‘Single phase panel’? You need two phases.

@JonCuster "single phase" includes US split phase

The error is calling it a 120V 200A panel. The odds that it's 120 rather than 240 (split phase) are on a par with the odds that I'll win the lottery. Depending exactly where it is there are higher odds that it could be 208/120, but most likely it's 240 and then the power label indicates 5200W (only 21.67A) on the "similar" oven.

My mistake. I have two hots coming into the main panel. Split phase. 120/240.

@Ecnerwal I've updated my original post on the main panel. Got it. So I'm still safe with 10-3 and a 30a breaker. I can go with the higher wattage but divide by 240 instead of 120 and still under 30 amps. Super helpful!

Maybe it's just dirty from sitting, but if that's "gently used" I'd hate to see "thrashed."

Technology Connections on 120V  also that sticker says 5200W. Remember you can [edit] your question.  Also, QR codes have some error correction, so that 90% of a QR code might work.

Call Miele, ask them if there is some way to identify the model without the sticker.  You may need to disassemble it and and look at part numbers on the control board or elsewhere.   You can't go by appearances.  There are many variations of appliances that look exactly the same and intentionally differ in power or features.  This can be changes from year to year, or offering an oven at two price points with different features enabled inside.  You cannot assume or compare from the outside.

@Harper-ReinstateMonica, it's a badly damaged Data Matrix code, not a QR code.  My scanner won't recognize it, but manually decoding says it starts with "0000????3624".

The key is the model #: H4880BP. That led me to this sales page, which has the key specification of Amps: 30. That's really all you need to know. It is possible that your oven is a different model, but I highly suspect that given that it is the same brand and the same size/type (particularly a single oven rather than a double oven) that the current requirement is going to be the same. 30A is pretty standard for a single oven.
The whole 240/208/120 thing is standard for ovens made for sale in the US/Canada and you don't need to be too concerned about the details. You also can't tell anything from the rated power (5200W/3900W) because ovens have special rules. (If this was a simple resistance space heater and it showed those numbers, yes you would just divide to get the Amps.)
Wire up 10 AWG 4-wire cable or 4 wires in conduit. Hot, hot, neutral, ground.
I seem to be getting quite a few comments and downvotes based on the indefinite identification and the "120V panel".

120V panel

Extremely unlikely. I am pretty well convinced that is a misunderstanding by OP. A picture of the main panel would resolve that pretty quickly. If there are any double-breakers (other than the subpanel feed) then it can't possibly be a 120V (i.e., only one active hot or the two hots tied to one single hot feed) panel.

Maybe it is a different oven and needs more power

This is possible. But while I wouldn't be surprised if it is a slightly different model, based on general experience (not a guarantee), a given manufacturer (in this case Miele) is unlikely to have some models of a single (as opposed to double) oven with significantly different power supply requirements. The current model (as referenced via the Craigs List pictures) is a 30A oven and it is loaded with self-cleaning and all kinds of special cooking modes.
That being said, running 8 AWG wire so that the circuit could be upgraded (by swapping the breaker) to 40A if needed is not that unreasonable, particularly if it is a fairly short run. I doubt that will be needed here but the next oven could be a different brand that needs 40A or a double-oven which is much more likely to need 40A.
When my electrician installed my Kitchenaid double-oven > 20 years ago, he was quite surprised to find it needed a 40A circuit. 30A was - and still is- quite common for single and, I think (but can't find any at the moment) even some double ovens. I have even found some single ovens that only require 20A. Is it possible Miele used to need 40A and now only needs 30A? Yes. Likely? No.
And finally, thanks to limequokka, we know the model is a H4881BP, likely the successor to H4880BP, and it is definitely a 30A oven.

...on the rather huge assumption that the similar-looking oven is, in fact, the exact same oven the OP has. The damaged illegible label has a QR code the "similar-looking oven" label lacks, for the most obvious clue that it might not be so. It also has a vertical line before the voltage part of the label starts.

I had to downvote this, given the "you don't need to be too concerned about the details" statement and the OP's very clear statement that they are wanting to connect this 240V (or 208V) product to a sub panel off of a "single phase 120v 200a main panel". At an absolute best case something was transcribed incorrectly into the question. However, the fact that those statements are there in the question, and the oven is clearly incompatible with that (even though the statement is likely wrong, and probably compatible), it's definitely not "you don't need to be too concerned about the details".

This answer is really good. I now understand why my (double) oven cycles the heating elements instead of using them all at the same time and thereby sacrificing efficiency - there is a common assumption that wiring is a mere 30A so they implemented a conservative approach. So much for having wired the oven location with 4AWG copper

@AlessioSangalli Pretty much all double-ovens have this issue. The actual number may be 30A or may be 40A - varies by brand and model. But even with 40A there are limits, resulting in some controlled cycling between the ovens and, in particular, I am pretty sure this is why most (possibly all, but I haven't done a survey) double-ovens do not let you use the other oven at all while you have one of the ovens in self-cleaning mode.

Yeah I understand that in self-cleaning mode it's best to not overload the whole cabinet with so much heat. However, it's really disappointing that even if each single oven has three separate elements, they are only used in a round-robin way; my oven does the following:
10s - 9A bottom element
10s - 16A broiler
40s - 8A central back element

@AlessioSangalli I don't think it is about overloading the cabinet with heat. Modern ovens are incredibly well insulated. I think it is all about not using too much power at one time.

You don't need to make assumptions, there is enough information still on the panel. You appear to have a Miele model H4881BP (serial number 59883628).
The scannable data matrix code, while damaged, is still mostly there and like QR codes, these use lots of fancy maths to allow them to still work while large chunks are missing. I recreated the code including the standard border so it would actually scan:

It outputted your serial number: 000059883628, which could be used on the Miele website to get a manual (download link)
Here's the relevant page from the manual, hopefully that clears up what you need (30A):


Fantastic! And welcome to DIY!

Damn impressive sleuthing there !   Keep it up !

Rep bonus awarded.

Wow. Thank you so much.

@JeremyP.Beasley Glad I could be of help :)

@Criggie Thanks mate, glad you liked it :)

The oven requires 240/120V or 208/120V service (120V hot to neutral, either 240 or 208 V hot to hot, with the latter being a side effect of being one phase of a particular sort of 3-phase transformer) on a 4-wire cable (or conduit) that has hot, hot, neutral and ground, as opposed to a 240/208V-only hot, hot & ground or a 120V-only hot, neutral and ground.
That basically means that most likely the lightbulb and the clock/control work on 120V, and the heating element will work on 240V at 5200W or 208V at 3900W.
120V to the heating element is not a supported mode of operation.
As for "making safe assumptions" you really should verify that all the "similar looking" ovens from the same manufacturer have the same power ratings, rather than a single example. Or contact the manufacturer for help in determining which exact model you have, so they can supply a replacement label.

I agree with this. The OP should, at a minimum, test the equipment using some type of kill-a-watt device.  I'm sure the OP would NOT want to be faced with the consequences of an unsafe reality due to the assumption made based on other people quesses.

Contacting manufacturer (answer) eliminates uncertainty.   Measuring current (comment above) slightly improves your chances of guessing correctly.  Not good enough IMO. You want certainty.  To measure, you need to know what program settings plus food/environmental conditions plus timing creates max power demand.  Even if OP had the manual it would be hard to know that, and he does not have it.

@gns100 A "kill-a-watt" type device won't exist for a 240 V oven, it will be a clamp meter. Even if you do, it won't be safe because you don't know what the worst-case design conditions are, for example freezing cold elements and a seized fan or max blast self clean mode.

240V kill-a-watt style meters absolutely do exist, just not for the US split phase design.   So yes a clamp meter on each leg is the correct solution here.

You say in comments that you do in fact have 240V service.
The "120/2xx" voltage slash rating means the oven contains BOTH 120V AND 240V loads, and as such, needs to be provided both 240V hot phases and a neutral (if you just went "whaaaaaa?" see Technology Connections).
This type of connection is dangerous to connect ungrounded. A loose neutral wire will energize the chassis of the oven.  So you're going to want a 4-wire w/ground connection.  Note that so-called "/2+ground" cable is never appropriate since the +ground found in such cable is NOT rated to be neutral. And you need neutral.
Now if you look at the schematic, you may find you only need neutral for the oven light. The very idea of 120V oven lights was so consumers could use the normal 120V incandescent bulb they use everywhere else in their house, in the 20th century LOL. Since CFL/LED, this plan is nonsense and you need to buy special oven lights anyway, so they might as well be 240V.  Not saying to modify your oven to avoid a neutral requirement LOL.
Anyway, to come back around to the slash rating, it means both hots must be only 120V from neutral, as they are in 120/240V and 120/208V.  It is forbidding use on 2 legs of "wild leg delta" since the hots are not insulated for the wild leg's higher voltage to neutral.
Given that the oven's thermal rating is a wildcard, gosh, you could try energizing it and measuring it with a clamp meter when placed on "cleaning cycle" or other extreme - note the elements will thermostatically click on and off once they reach temperature so the measurements must be done immediately.  But in an abundance of caution, I would run 8 AWG SE-R type cable, which is 4-wire. SER is allowed 75C thermal rating which means it's safe to 50A even though it is #8.  You can try it with a 30A breaker, but if you get trips, or your clamp meter says otherwise, bump the breaker since the wire has headroom.

According to my experience even when starting from cold, elements will cycle anyway, no need to reach temperature.
